# Update / edit django object after selecting it from a dropdown list

Tags: django, forms, post

I want to update / edit a product from a page by clicking a form button (UPDATE) after selecting product from a dropdown list or an auto-complete list.

`List.html` page works fine while clicking on UPDATE button `update.html` page cannot parse the POST data.
Manually I could access `update.html` with pk suffix (/update/1/), it is working fine too.

How can I pass pk's value alone to url?

views.py

```
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'update.html'
    model = Product
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'image', 'file',]
    success_url = '/list/'

class ProductsView(ListView,):
    template_name = 'list.html'
    model = Product
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', ProductsView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
]
```

list.html

```
<body>
 <form method='POST' action='/update/'> {% csrf_token %}
  <select name='pk'>
   {% for obj in object_list %}
    <option value='{{ obj.id }}'>{{ obj.name }}</option>    
   {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value='UPDATE'>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you can make ajax request on change event of select box.

Comment: You have not included `update.html` page in your question. Show us how are you updating your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by only using `<select>`

```
<select name="select_path" id="select_path"
  ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  {% for obj in object_list %}
   <option value="{% url app_name:update obj.id %}">{{ obj.name }} 
   </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

You just need to change the option value, I don't know the exact url, tewak as per your requirement.

Comment: This one works when selecting a value so for the initial value it will not work.
Selecting value from dropdown list is not practical actually we need an auto complete box and submit button to select from 100s of selection values.

Thanks, anyway nice attempt, it works only when selection changes.

Comment: With following code we could do the same without initial value problem.

` <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a value to Update
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      {% for i in students %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'updating' i.id %}">{{i.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late but this answer will definitely help someone.

```
<select name="select_path" id="select_path">
  <option value="{{ initial_value }}">{{ initial_value name }}</option>
  {% for obj in object_list %}
   <option value="{{ edited object value }}">{{ edited obj.name }} 
   </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Get the value normally as you would when saving a form.